# CSS columns floating blocks right

Tags: html, css

I have a block grid that I am using CSS columns with to try and create a masonry effect. I've achieved that so far, however the last block item always seems to float to the right.

What I have done so far is
1) on the block grid container set

```
.blog-grid {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: rem-calc(20); 
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px; 
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 30px;
    column-fill: auto;
  }
```

2) and on the block

```
.blog-item {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: 
    -moz-column-break-inside: 
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

3) Here is the PHP/HTML

```
<section class="blog-grid">
                    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style"> 
                <article class="border half-orange">
                    <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/">
                                                <img src="" alt="RVC Management Committee">
                    </a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/"><h3 class="orange">RVC Management Committee</h3></a>

                        <h3 class="orange">17-09-2015</h3>

                        <p>In February 2015, our CEO, Graham Godden was privileged to be invited to become a Surrey School Governor and join… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/">read post</a></p>

                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/"><h3 class="orange">Read more &gt;</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
                    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style"> 
                <article class="border half-teal">
                    <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/">
                                                <img src="" alt="International Association of Women Police Conference, Cardiff">
                    </a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/"><h3 class="teal">International Association of Women Police Conference, Cardiff</h3></a>

                        <h3 class="teal">17-09-2015</h3>

                        <p>On Monday 24th August, Yes+ Trustee, Jackie Malton, CEO Graham Godden and Senior Practitioner, Marticka Sampson, were delighted to present… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/">read post</a></p>

                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/"><h3 class="teal">Read more &gt;</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
                    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style"> 
                <article class="border half-red">
                    <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/">
                                                <img src="" alt="Yes+ Team Building Day">
                    </a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/"><h3 class="red">Yes+ Team Building Day</h3></a>

                        <h3 class="red">17-09-2015</h3>

                        <p>Our first Staff Team Building Day took place on 29th July. The aim of the day was to improve morale… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/">read post</a></p>

                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/"><h3 class="red">Read more &gt;</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
                    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style"> 
                <article class="border half-yellow">
                    <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/">
                                                <img src="" alt="McGrath Support for Yes+">
                    </a>

                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/"><h3 class="yellow">McGrath Support for Yes+</h3></a>

                        <h3 class="yellow">17-09-2015</h3>

                        <p>Yes+ have been selected from over 150 charities to receive a support package from leading philanthropists Harvey and Allison McGrath.… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/">read post</a></p>

                        <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/"><h3 class="yellow">Read more &gt;</h3></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
                    </section>
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce anything.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a live demo, or at least some HTML? Usually we will need to be able to recreate your problem to be able to help. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I've added the HTML, unfortunately there is nothing live yet

Comment: Instead of the HTML you gave us, load the page on your local and get the actual output and paste that here.

Comment: That will help. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at what your code is doing, I'm not sure `column-count` is what you want. `column-count` just takes everything and formats it into columns with no regard to container. You might want to look into `flexbox` for this. Not sure what the end result you want to achieve is.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `flexbox` approach with your HTML structure, but new CSS:

HTML

```
<section class="blog-grid">
    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style">
        <article class="border half-orange"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/">
                                                <img src="" alt="RVC Management Committee">
                    </a>

            <div class="content"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/"><h3 class="orange">RVC Management Committee</h3></a>

                 <h3 class="orange">17-09-2015</h3>

                <p>In February 2015, our CEO, Graham Godden was privileged to be invited to become a Surrey School Governor and join… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/">read post</a>

                </p> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/rvc-management-committee/"><h3 class="orange">Read more &gt;</h3></a>

            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style">
        <article class="border half-teal"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/">
                                                <img src="" alt="International Association of Women Police Conference, Cardiff">
                    </a>

            <div class="content"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/"><h3 class="teal">International Association of Women Police Conference, Cardiff</h3></a>

                 <h3 class="teal">17-09-2015</h3>

                <p>On Monday 24th August, Yes+ Trustee, Jackie Malton, CEO Graham Godden and Senior Practitioner, Marticka Sampson, were delighted to present… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/">read post</a>

                </p> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/international-association-of-women-police-conference-cardiff/"><h3 class="teal">Read more &gt;</h3></a>

            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style">
        <article class="border half-red"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/">
                                                <img src="" alt="Yes+ Team Building Day">
                    </a>

            <div class="content"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/"><h3 class="red">Yes+ Team Building Day</h3></a>

                 <h3 class="red">17-09-2015</h3>

                <p>Our first Staff Team Building Day took place on 29th July. The aim of the day was to improve morale… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/">read post</a>

                </p> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/yes-team-building-day/"><h3 class="red">Read more &gt;</h3></a>

            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item no-custom-style">
        <article class="border half-yellow"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/">
                                                <img src="" alt="McGrath Support for Yes+">
                    </a>

            <div class="content"> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/"><h3 class="yellow">McGrath Support for Yes+</h3></a>

                 <h3 class="yellow">17-09-2015</h3>

                <p>Yes+ have been selected from over 150 charities to receive a support package from leading philanthropists Harvey and Allison McGrath.… <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/">read post</a>

                </p> <a href="http://yesplus.al.home.dev/news/mcgrath-support-for-yes/"><h3 class="yellow">Read more &gt;</h3></a>

            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.blog-grid {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-content:flex-start;
  }

.blog-item {
    flex:1 0 33.3333%;
    padding:25px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/08vp50fL/

This will give you a pseudo masonry affect and keeps content left aligned once the wrap occurs. Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: Tried your approach, and wasn't able to get anywhere. I've put things on a server now. This is the page that I was having issues with
http://yesplus.stage.philosophydesign.com/about-us/our-team/#panel-staff